# Probability distribution defined by partitioning an interval

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to efficiently sample from a known probability distribution.

If I have the interval $I=[0,m]$, and consider a partition on $I$ consisting of $n$ bins, how do I then uniformly draw a random variable $X$ which has the value $X \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with probability given by the widths of the corresponding bin?

I have been drawing a uniform variate between $0$ and $m$, and then determining which bin it is in, but this quite is slow for large $n$.

Comment: Look up `Differences` and `RandomChoice` (with weights).

Comment: Ok `RandomChoice`, I think that will work.

Comment: Never use an upper-case letter for a variable as it will conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

Comment: You want to "draw a random sample from a random variable $X$" rather than "uniformly draw a random variable $X$" as "uniformly" implies that the bin widths are all equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = 20;
n = 4;
binlims = {0, 2, 9, 14, 20};
binlengths = Differences[binlims];
```

### RandomChoice

```
SeedRandom[1]
rc = RandomChoice[binlengths -> Range[4], 20]
```

> {4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2}

### WeightedData + EmpiricalDistribution + RandomVariate

```
SeedRandom[1]
rved = RandomVariate[EmpiricalDistribution[WeightedData[Range[4], binlengths]], 20]
```

> {4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2}

### UniformDistribution + TransformedDistribution + RandomVariate

This mimics the description of the process used to generate the random variable `X`, but it is much slower than the previous two methods.

```
ClearAll[pw]
pw[x_] := Piecewise[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, #] &@(# <= x < #2 & @@@ 
   Partition[binlims, 2, 1])];

pw[x]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  1 & 0\leq x<2 \\
>  2 & 2\leq x<9 \\
>  3 & 9\leq x<14 \\
>  4 & 14\leq x<20
> \end{cases}$

```
SeedRandom[1]
rvtd = RandomVariate[TransformedDistribution[pw[x], 
   Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{0, m}]]], 20]
```

> {4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2}

When used with the same `RandomSeed` all three methods give the same result. The first two are roughly equal in terms of speed.

```
rc == rved  == rvtd
```

> True

Comment: Thank you, that is a big help.